# data from iPhone to php

Tags: iphone

i have this in Xcode:

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"message";
```

this string i want to send to myadress.php. anybody help me with some good reference or code please.

this is my php side:

```
<?

$connect = mysql_connect ("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());

$feed = $_GET['feed_message'];

$login = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feedback SET feed_message ='".$feed."'", $connect) or die(mysql_error());


mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: try : http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use or https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: You might also want to read up about SQL Injection and security.

Comment: @meccan ASIHTTPRequest, tragically, is now deprecated and the developer recommends not using it anymore. AFNetworking does seem a popular choice to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and you need implement the NSURLConnection delegate method

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yoururl"];
    NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlReq delegate:self];
    [connection start];
```

You can also use ASIHttpRequest, it has more Features.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you just want to send a request to specific URL containing parameter "feed_message":

```
http://myserver.com/myscrypt.php?feed_message=message
```

To do it you need:

a. Create an url:

```
NSString * scriptURLString = @"http://myserver.com/myscrypt.php";
NSString * parameterName = @"feed_message";
NSString * post = @"message";
NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@=%@",scriptURLString, parameterName, post];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

b. send request to url. There are many ways to do it depending on your needs.

You may send asynchronous request (set delegate property and implement delegate methods to handle results)

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] delegate:nil];
```

or simply use NSData synchronous method:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```